# How to get access to google spreadsheets from telegram bot on phone?

Tags: java, google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api, telegram-bot

I have simple telegram bot which allows read and write some data in a certain google spreadsheet. I need to make sure that authorization takes place on the device on which I run it. Because this is telegram bot i can use it through phone but this way i still have to authorize(i.e. give permission in my app to make changes to the google spreadsheet) on the PC. I think integrating google sign-in will help me but i dont know how to use it.

Just in case i'm attaching the code:

```
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.SheetsScopes;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.model.*;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.Sheets;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Quickstart {

    /**
     * Application name.
     */
    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME =
            "Google Sheets API Java ua.telegrambot.movies.services.Quickstart";

    /**
     * Directory to store user credentials for this application.
     */
    private static final java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR = new java.io.File(
            System.getProperty("user.home"), ".credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-java-quickstart");

    /**
     * Global instance of the {@link FileDataStoreFactory}.
     */
    private static FileDataStoreFactory DATA_STORE_FACTORY;

    /**
     * Global instance of the JSON factory.
     */
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY =
            JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

    /**
     * Global instance of the HTTP transport.
     */
    private static HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT;

    /**
     * Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart.
     * <p>
     * If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
     * at ~/.credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-java-quickstart
     */
    private static final List<String> SCOPES =
            Arrays.asList(SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS);

    static {
        try {
            HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
            DATA_STORE_FACTORY = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates an authorized Credential object.
     *
     * @return an authorized Credential object.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static Credential authorize() throws IOException {
        // Load client secrets.
        InputStream in =
                Quickstart.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secret.json");
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
                GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
                new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                        HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                        .setDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_FACTORY)
                        .setAccessType("offline")
                        .build();
        Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(
                flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
        System.out.println(
                "Credentials saved to " + DATA_STORE_DIR.getAbsolutePath());
        return credential;
    }

    /**
     * Build and return an authorized Sheets API client service.
     *
     * @return an authorized Sheets API client service
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static Sheets getSheetsService() throws IOException {
        Credential credential = authorize();
        return new Sheets.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();
    }

    public static List<List<Object>> getSpreadSheetRecords(String spreadsheetId, String range) throws IOException {
        Sheets service = getSheetsService();
        ValueRange response = service.spreadsheets().values()
                .get(spreadsheetId, range)
                .execute();
        List<List<Object>> values = response.getValues();
        if (values != null && values.size() != 0) {
            return values;
        } else {
            System.out.println("No data found.");
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void appendNewSheetRecords(String spreadsheetId, String range, List<List<Object>> values) throws IOException {
        Sheets service = getSheetsService();
        ValueRange body = new ValueRange()
                .setValues(values);
//        UpdateValuesResponse result =
//                service.spreadsheets().values().update(spreadsheetId, range, body)
//                        .setValueInputOption("RAW")
//                        .execute();
        AppendValuesResponse appendResult = service.spreadsheets().values()
                .append(spreadsheetId, range, body)
                .setValueInputOption("USER_ENTERED")
                .setInsertDataOption("INSERT_ROWS")
                .setIncludeValuesInResponse(true)
                .execute();

        ValueRange total = appendResult.getUpdates().getUpdatedData();
        System.out.println(total);
    }

}
```

Comment: You may want to check this [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mKSXd_od4Lg) on how to connect your Telegram Bot to a Google Spreadsheet but using Apps Script. This [library](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot) also provides a pure Python interface for the [Telegram Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api). It's compatible with Python versions 2.7, 3.3+ and [PyPy](http://pypy.org/). It also works with [Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine).